# java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1 error

Tags: java, jdbc

I looked for this error in other stackoverflow problems but basically the solutions given are the same thing as my code I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
public List<ProjectUser> findProjectUserId(int id){
     List <ProjectUser> users= new ArrayList<>();
     ProjectUser projectuser= null;
     try {
         String req="select * from projectuser where project=?";
         PreparedStatement ps= cnx.getConnection().prepareStatement(req);
         ResultSet rs= ps.executeQuery();
         ps.setInt(1,id);
         while (rs.next()){
            projectuser= new ProjectUser(rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2), rs.getInt(3));
             users.add(projectuser);
         }
     } catch (SQLException ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }
     return users;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should to execute your Stetement after you set Paramettres :

```
ps.setInt(1,id);//set param
ResultSet rs= ps.executeQuery();//then execute your statement
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to set the bind value after executing the query, instead of before it. Flip the order around, and you should be OK:

```
PreparedStatement ps = cnx.getConnection().prepareStatement(req);
ps.setInt(1,id);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you everyone lack of sleeping problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the query before setting the parameters of the PreparedStatement. That is why your code is giving Exception. The order of the statements should be

```
ps.setInt(1,id); 
ResultSet rs= ps.executeQuery();
```